# How do I make ADX go green or red dependent on its value?

Tags: pine-script

Hi I am trying to make my ADX plot line format conditionally. I would like it to go green when <=0.15 and red when below this number. I have the following so far but I cant get it to work

```
////////ADX
len = input(14)
th = input(0.15)

TrueRange = max(max(high-low, abs(high-nz(close[1]))), abs(low-nz(close[1])))
DirectionalMovementPlus = high-nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1])-low ? max(high-nz(high[1]), 0): 0
DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1])-low > high-nz(high[1]) ? max(nz(low[1])-low, 0): 0

SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange

SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus

SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementMinus

DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange 
DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange 
DX = abs(DIPlus-DIMinus) / (DIPlus+DIMinus)
ADX = sma(DX, len)
adxup = ADX>=0.15
adxdown = ADX<0.15
plotColour = (ADX > 0.15) ? green : red

plot(ADX, color=plotColour, linewidth=3)
hline(th, color=color.black)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope you are well.

v5 came out today so this may be a version mix, as well this script looks like it may have come from v3. You should be up and running by ensuring to have the following lines in place: first we need to make sure the version is 4 and that study is specified. Next on our plotColour line we need to bring up the colour from green to color.green etc. as seen below

```
//@version=4
study('Blake ADX')

plotColour = (ADX > th) ? color.green : color.red
```

Alternatively, we could bring the whole works up to v5:

```
//@version=5
indicator('Blake ADX')

len = input(14)
th = input(0.15)

TrueRange = math.max(math.max(high - low, math.abs(high - nz(close[1]))), math.abs(low - nz(close[1])))
DirectionalMovementPlus = high - nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1]) - low ? math.max(high - nz(high[1]), 0) : 0
DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1]) - low > high - nz(high[1]) ? math.max(nz(low[1]) - low, 0) : 0

SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) / len + TrueRange

SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) / len + DirectionalMovementPlus

SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) / len + DirectionalMovementMinus

DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange
DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange
DX = math.abs(DIPlus - DIMinus) / (DIPlus + DIMinus)
ADX = ta.sma(DX, len)
adxup = ADX >= th
adxdown = ADX < th
plotColour = adxup ? color.green : color.red

plot(ADX, color=plotColour, linewidth=3)
hline(th, color=color.black)
```

Cheers from a fellow Canadian ;)

Comment: Thanks Bjorgum. I really need to buy you a drink or 10 :)